# Mom passes away 2015, Sister living in her house rent free

Tags: mortgage

- My mom passed 2015.
- My nieces and nephew [from 2nd sister] lived there and then they moved out in 2016
- My older sister started living in my mom's house 2016. She sold her house in 7 days and moved into my mom's with the plan to fix it up to sell it.
- I live on the east coast and my other sister lives locally to my sister.
- We all agreed to this arrangement.
- Even as of Aug 2018 and she's still "fixing" the house. She's big into these home shows and she's doing quite a bit of renovation.
- We just wanted to fix major stuff i.e Foundation,  roof, exterior, carpet and the bathroom.
- However She's putting in back splashes, barn yard sliding doors etc. She's put about $15,000 so far into it.
- It's becoming a lot because we want the house sold and over and done with.
- I asked her to buy me out and we got into a huge fight. Currently we are not on talking terms.
- She's living there rent/mortgage free. She pays all the property taxes, insurance and utils.

My question:

1. How will this split of money happen if she continues to live in this
   house?
2. How will the split be when she decides to put it on market?

Will she take her share as well as whatever she's paid over the last 2-3 yrs?

If So it will leave not much for me and my other sister.
I want to know what the options are?
Does she have the right to take out property tax, insurance and real estate costs out of the sale? Plus the $15,000 for renovations?

The house will probably sell for around $100,000.

PS:
I have no clue if the deed is in her name or my mom's. She took over my mom's care when my mom got sick and she handled a lot of that details mainly because I've lived out of state for over 20 yrs and my other sister is basically a flake. So no one trusted her to deal with finances.

I know its is terrible when a parent dies and leaves no Will in place and I hate fighting with my siblings. However I also want things to move along and if she wants to live in the house; I am OK with it but I'd prefer she buy us out and just tell us that.

Comment: If there's no will in place, state probate law applies, which varies from state to state. You need a local probate attorney if you can't work out a deal with the sister.

Comment: Was the house entirely in your mother's name? Have you taken any sort of formal action since your mother's death? I.e who holds the deeds, was there a contract written. On the whole its probably most cost effective if you can solve this between yourselves, rather than involving a lawyer, since the split sum won't be huge anyway. That route would put this as an IPS question though, rather than a legal one.

Comment: I would ask for a consultation with a real estate lawyer (or even several) and explain the situation.  These are usually free and are there for the lawyers to discuss if the case has any merit before you take further action.  In the U.S., recouping legal fees is pretty typical in complaint requests and sinking 15,000 into a 100,00 house is a huge expense.

Comment: "I have no clue if the deed is in her name or my mom's." This is critically important in answering the question. Also it matters which country and if the U.S., which U.S. state, the house is located in.